# Allow custom item "Always on Top" to be available when right-clicking the title bar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I customize the system menu of a Windows Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615940/how-can-i-customize-the-system-menu-of-a-windows-form)

I am just wondering, how can I add a custom menu item to the system menu of windows form?

By default, we only get to see `restore`, `move`, 'size', 'minimize', `maximize`, and `close` options. What should I do here so I will be able to add, say "**Always on Top**" option (click to check/uncheck)? Is there any existing example of this?

Thanks

Comment: This menu is called the "System Menu". See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615940/how-can-i-customize-the-system-menu-of-a-windows-form

Comment: Note, while you can customise the system menu, a "always on top" option is not possible: [*How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx).