# App menu item adding WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menu, addition

In WinForms, is there a way to add an item to the popup menu when you click on the icon in the  forms control bar? Apps I can think off that use this is Chrome, and Command Prompt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I customize the system menu of a Windows Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615940/how-can-i-customize-the-system-menu-of-a-windows-form)

Answer (score 0):

there are no methods built into the BCL, but you can always pinvoke the Win32 functions.  Check out [InsertMenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a starting point.