# Title-bar's context menu

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I customize the system menu of a Windows Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615940/how-can-i-customize-the-system-menu-of-a-windows-form)

How could I insert new items to the title-bar's context menu as in Google's Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

I would prefer a C# WPF solution, but I have no problem to do this in C++ (Interops are all set already).

Thank you.

Comment: I found some good threads . [How can I customize the system menu of a Windows Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4616637/359170) [This application demonstrates how to modify a winform application’s system menu. (CSCustomizeSysMenu)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSCustomizeSysMenu-024ccb7f) I think they will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other alternatives here:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70568/An-MVVM-friendly-approach-to-adding-system-menu-en
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/320885/Customize-Window-System-Menu-in-WPF

You might consider using the 2nd link where it actually creates a WPF menu instead of modifying the existing native system menu, if you wanted to skin the menu for your application.

I'd suggest you extended the code to scan the native System Menu so you could create WPF menu items that mirrored the expected System Menu items.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.