# creating about dialog box in C# form application

Tags: c#, forms

I have a C# form application, in that I have a menu where one of the item is `help`. It has a sub-item `About`. As you seen in many applications when you click on help a separate dialog box opens up which displays the information.

I want something like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add a menu to a Windows Form at design time
Open the form you wish to add a menu to in the Windows Forms Designer.

- In the Toolbox, `double-click` the `MenuStrip` component.
- A menu is added to the form (displaying the text "Type Here"), and the MainMenu component is added to the component tray.

Then you can do that as follows using click Event of that particuler subMenu item .
Hint:Just click the subMenu item and `rightclick->Properties`..then you can find the `Click Event` for `subMenuItem`.

```
 private void aboutToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    AboutWindow aboutWindow = new AboutWindow();
    aboutWindow.Show();
 }
```

Comment: Use .ShowDialog() method if you want to disable user interaction with any form other than the AboutBox.

Answer (score 33):

Here it goes, just add one using predefined template:

[image: Add item window]

And you could possibly find this link useful:

[social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1302af39-a9ab-4f9c-b607-63f7c75939cf/about-box?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

Quote from there:

> 1. Create a new windows form application
> 2. In the "Solution explorer" ,left part of the screen , right click on the name of your windows application.
> 3. Choose Add-->New item
> 4. From the " Add new item window" choose "AboutBox" , name it "AboutBox1" , click on Add button.
>    Now you have in your applicatoin two forms, "Form1" -- created by default by your project type and "AboutBox1" .
> 5. Right click on the "Form1" and choose "Design View".
> 6. Double click on the design sourface of form1.
> 7. After that you will see this code:
>
>    ```cs
>     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>     }
>    ```
> 8. Add this code to your application, to look like this:
>
>    ```cs
>     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         AboutBox1 a = new AboutBox1();
>         a.Show();
>     }
>    ```
> 9. Run the application.

Comment: If you like, show combo box in system menu: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616637/4608491

Answer (score 6):

There is a standard about box in the templates, try Project / Add new item and look for About Box.
You can show it like a regular dialog form, e.g. using
    new AboutBox(this). ShowDialog();
in the menu item click handler.

Answer (score 2):

Before or after adding About Box to the project from the list of possible items, make sure that AssemblyInfo.cs is fulfilled with data.

[AssemblyInfo.cs in Solution Explorer Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soVfb.png)

In your project, click on Properties.
Open AssemblyInfo.cs.
This is the source of the info displayed in About Box.