# TextBox contextmenu

Tags: c#, user32

I've spend a few days wondering how to append new items to default context menu in TextBox.  Code below was taken from question [How can I customize the system menu of a Windows Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615940/how-can-i-customize-the-system-menu-of-a-windows-form) but is good only for context menu of main form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class CustomForm : Form
{
    // P/Invoke constants
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    private const int MF_STRING = 0x0;
    private const int MF_SEPARATOR = 0x800;

    // P/Invoke declarations
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AppendMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InsertMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uPosition, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);


    // ID for the About item on the system menu
    private int SYSMENU_ABOUT_ID = 0x1;

    public CustomForm()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);

        // Get a handle to a copy of this form's system (window) menu
        IntPtr hSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);

        // Add a separator
        AppendMenu(hSysMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, string.Empty);

        // Add the About menu item
        AppendMenu(hSysMenu, MF_STRING, SYSMENU_ABOUT_ID, "&About…");
    }


}
```

My idea was to use :

```
        IntPtr texthandle = this.textbox1.contextmenu.handle;
```

Instead of :

```
    IntPtr hSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);
```

But in debugger context menu of textbox is always null which indicates error (acces to null reference ). I think that problem is that context menu of textbox is initialized by right click event in Windows system. Do you have any idea how to deal with this problem (modify default context menu ).

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c++]?

Comment: user32.dll has been written in C (probably in Microsoft Visual C++)

Comment: And in which way does this matter for the question? I don't see the point. [c:tag] is as wrong the same.

Comment: Why not replace it with a menu of your own? Much easier, imo..

Comment: @TaW it's not solution to solve this problem.

Comment: No. It is called a workaround. Often much better than the solution. The choice is yours..