# WPF Default menu

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF Application with right click default menu of WPF application (with Restore, Move, Size, Minimize, Maximize, Close Alt+F4)

My question: I want to add to this menu About options.
I can do it?

I want to use in the exist menu and to add About to this menu and not to create a new menu!

Thanks.

Before:

[image: Menu before]

After

[image: Before/After]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// P/Invoke constants
private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
private const int MF_STRING = 0x0;
private const int MF_SEPARATOR = 0x800;

// P/Invoke declarations
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool AppendMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InsertMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uPosition, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);

// ID for the About item on the system menu
private int SYSMENU_ABOUT_ID = 0x1;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    var source = (HwndSource) PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
    source.AddHook(WndProc);

    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    // Get a handle to a copy of this form's system (window) menu
    IntPtr hSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(helper.Handle, false);

    // Add a separator
    AppendMenu(hSysMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, string.Empty);

    // Add the About menu item
    AppendMenu(hSysMenu, MF_STRING, SYSMENU_ABOUT_ID, "&About…");
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    // Handle messages...
    // Test if the About item was selected from the system menu
    if ((msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) && ((int)wParam == SYSMENU_ABOUT_ID))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Custom About Dialog");
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Source: [How can I customize the system menu of a Windows Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615940/how-can-i-customize-the-system-menu-of-a-windows-form) modified to make it work in WPF