# Injecting a custom menu item into an external application

Tags: c#, winforms

Is is possible in .net to inject a custom menu option into an external applications context menu. Both applications are .net and it is a standard context menu on a gridview.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but not so simple, unless you just want to add one item to the end of the menu...

Have a look at this set of answers, which cover the scenario in detail: [How can I customize the system menu of a Windows Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615940/how-can-i-customize-the-system-menu-of-a-windows-form)